# how can I find what condition defaulted to true?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In javascript I have an if statement and I want to log the first condition that defaulted to true. For instance if `a === true` then I want to `console.log` a (**update**: e.g., "a" or "b" or "c", the actual character).

Any ideas?

```
if(a || b || c){ console.log(this) }
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you want to log the names (`a`, `b` or `c`) or the values of these variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is, of course, [use a debugger](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) and inspect `a`, `b`, and/or `c` when you branch into the `if` statement's body. :-)

Doing it in code, <s>there's no shortcut if you're really trying to see "a", "b", or "c"</s> **update** what was I thinking? Of course there's a shortcut:

```
if(a || b || c){
    console.log(a ? "a" : b ? "b" : "c");
}
```

Or if you want to see the value as well:

```
if(a || b || c){
    console.log(a ? "a: " + a : b ? "b: " + b : "c: " + c);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/odataq) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/odataq/edit)

---

Original longer version:

```
if(a || b || c){
    if (a) {
        console.log("a: " + a);
    }
    else if (b) {
        console.log("b: " + b);
    }
    else {
        console.log("c: " + c);
    }
}
```

Or (and this is quite tricky and *much* longer, so not recommended):

```
if(a || b || c){
    switch (false) {
        case !a:
            console.log("a: " + a);
            break;
        case !b:
            console.log("b: " + b);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("c: " + c);
    }
}
```

...which works because `switch` statement `case`s are evaluated at runtime, and in order.

Comment: @gdoron: No, I said if he really wants to see "a", "b", or "c" (the actual characters, not whatever the variables with those names contain).

Comment: your examples needlessly checks the state of the variables twice, there is no need for you to have the `if(a||b||c)`, expect that in your second example, you assume that if a and b are both false c MUST be true.

Comment: @thecoshman: It's debugging code the OP's putting within the branch that's been taken. And re the second example, read again: If a and b are falsey, c *must* be truthy (because of the up-front check you just complained about). I actually felt yours failed to capture the OP's point -- but didn't think it was worth a downvote.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, in your second example, as it is, the default is right to assume that c is true, but you are still needlessly wrapping them with a the `if(a||b||c)`.

Comment: @thecoshman: **Again**, I'm doing that because it's clear (to me) that the OP is following that course in his *production* code and this is *debugging* code to find out why it branched that way.

Comment: yep thanks t.j crowder I wanted to see "a" or "b" or "c" the actual character. Sorry for the confusion guys and thanks for your help!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, I see where you are coming from. With the knowledge that there is a hidden 'more code here' you answer does indeed make sense, I take back my downvote :D

Comment: O.k. you got him right, not that I understand how you got that `this` is the var name and not it's value... =)

Comment: @climboid: **Doh!** What was I thinking? Of course there's a shorter way. See the update. Sorry about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder with your shorthand solution, this makes for a very neat solution. Well done

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to be honest, I hate the ternary operator and would much rather use a set of if/else as I feel it is a lot easier to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

just break out into chain of ifs.

```
if(a){
     // a is true, b and c unknown
} else if(b){
     // a is false, b is true, c is unknown
} else if (c){
     // a and b both false, c is true
} else {
     // a b and c all false
}
```

you can of course add more conditions to this if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a) {
   console.log(a);
   console.log(this);
} else if (b) {
   etc...
} else if (c) {
   etc...
} else {
   ... profit?
}
```

Another alternative, if you don't want to write out a long if/then/else chain, is to stuff the values you want to check into an array, loop over the array, then log/break when you hit the first true value.

Answer (score 0):

Save the first(if any) true variable, and use it:

```
var x = a || b || c ;
if(x){ console.log(x) }
```

**EDIT:** To clear up the confusion:

```
var a, b, c;
a = "";
b = null;
c = "12";

var x = a || b || c;

if (x) 
    alert(x);​ // Alerts "12" (and not "true").
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurWS/) to show that you will get the **value** of x, and not if x is true or not.

Comment: This is no different, you have simply moved the actual working out if any are true to outside the `if`, and added in a  variable to cache this result

Comment: @gdoron I think you got the OP wrong. Will revert the downvote if it turns out that I got him wrong...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder erm, as we are dealing with boolean values, the value of the 'truthy' item as you put it can only be true.

Comment: @gdoron the value of 'x' is not 'x', x can only ever be true or false in this example.

Comment: @thecoshman: What makes you think we're dealing with boolean values? And your following comment to gdoron is simply incorrect, `x` might well be `"hello, my name is x"`. In JavaScript, unlike some languages, `if ("hi there") { console.log("Yup"); }` outputs "Yup". Values used in conditions don't have to be strict booleans, they can be truthy or falsey. See [Section 9.2](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) of the spec.

Comment: @gdoron damn, I forgot about JS slutty types.

Comment: @gdoron yeah, surry bud, got a bit hasty with the up vote there. Whilst what are doing is clever, as (I think) you know your self, what you are doing here does not do what the OP requires. He would want to hae either 'a' 'b' or 'c' output, not the value of them

Comment: @thecoshman. He wrote it only later in a comment and T.J. Crowder updated the question. anyway. that up-down votes shouldn't be the highlights of the site. You can downvote if it will make you feel better.

Comment: @PeterG. You better see the fiddle. `x` isn't just true. it's the first truthy value!

Comment: @gdoron it's just that in relation to this question, your answer is not much use.

Comment: A, b and c don't necessary need to be bool's. Same is true for x. Point taken. But your code simply doesn't do, what to OP wants...

Comment: @PeterG.. All those -1\+1 discussion made me tired. You can do what ever you like to. I'm focusing at learning.

Answer (score 0):

another way via underscore.js

```
console.log(_.chain([a,b,c]).compact().first().value())
```